# ModalBottomSheet is showing above BottomBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottombar

I have `BottomBar` added in `ComposeActivity`. `BottomBar` is responsible for showing 3 composable. I don't want to add `ModalBottomSheet` to `Activity` instead I have added `ModalBottomSheet` inside 3rd Screen Composable. When `ModalBottomSheet` is invoked it is displayed above the `BottomBar`. How `ModalBottomSheet` can be displayed when Call to Action is done from 3rd screen Composable and it should be above `BottomBar`.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

It should display over `BottomBar` and on Bottom.

Comment: "I don't want to add ModalBottomSheet to Activity instead I have added ModalBottomSheet inside 3rd Screen Composable." - it sounds like you know exactly what your problem is. Your 3rd screen composable doesn't go over the bottom bar, so nothing within that is going to ever go over the bottom bar.

Comment: Can we hide BottomBar using call to action from 3rd screen Composable Logout click ?

Comment: ModalBottomSheetLayout sucks. If you have to control it in the root, it requires a really annoying task.

Comment: ModalBottomSheetLayout sucks. If you have to control it in the root, it requires a really annoying task.

Answer (score 8):

Just Position your ModalBottomSheetLayout on top of the Scaffold component.

Example:

```
AppTheme() {

   ModalBottomSheetLayout(){ //<-- Here

      Scaffold(){

                             //<-- Not Here or below

         NavigationGraph(){
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and call bottomSheet from NavHost.

Also you can hide Bottombar with action from screen but its long way;

*it may vary depending on your component child structure

Screen:

```
@Composable
fun 3rdScreen(onClickForHideBottomBar:() -> Unit){

    Button(onClick = { onClickForHideBottomBar()}) {

        Text(text = "Hide BottomBar")
    }
}
```

NavGraph:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(onClickForHideBottomBar:() -> Unit,){

    NavHost(){
         composable(){
             3rdScreen(onClickForHideBottomBar ={onClickForHideBottomBar()})
         }
    }
}
```

Scaffold:

```
var bottomBarVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {BottomNavigationView(bottomBarVisibility=bottomBarVisibility)}){

    NavigationGraph(onClickForHideBottomBar = bottomBarVisibility = !bottomBarVisibility){}
}
```

BottomNavigationView:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationView(bottomBarVisibility: Boolean){

    AnimatedVisibility(visibleState =MutableTransitionState(bottomBarVisibility)){

        BottomNavigation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use now [ModalBottomSheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)) by Compose Material 3.

Add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1"
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.1"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    var openBottomSheet by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var skipPartiallyExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = skipPartiallyExpanded
    )

    // Screen content
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            openBottomSheet = !openBottomSheet
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Show Bottom Sheet")
    }

    // When openBottomSheet is true, bottom sheet is visible.
    if (openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        ) {
            //Sheet content
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 32.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Your sheet content is here.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[closed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r9c4.png) and
[open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUx2A.png).

NOTE:
This API is undergoing frequent changes at the 1.1.x version. You must refer [official API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)) for more detailed description and example.